# El compilador angular no puede resolver todos los parámetros

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

Quiero agregar múltiples componentes en la misma página. Pero cuando agregué el encabezado del componente. No tenía más renderizado en el localhost. Pero si elimino el encabezado, vuelvo a tener el renderizado. Sin embargo, para el primer caso para el otro. Ya revisé [esta respuesta de Adrien Brunelat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47417216/4764604) pero parece que todo estuvo bien de mi parte.

## Main component

### app.component.html:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<app-menu></app-menu>
```

### app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'conFusion';
}
```

## Menu component

### menu.component.html

```
<div divFlex>
    <div>
        <h3>Menu</h3>
    </div>
</div>

<div divFlex>
    <mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="200px">
        <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let dish of dishes" (click) = onSelect(dish)>
            <img height="200px" src={{dish.image}} alt={{dish.name}}>
            <mat-grid-tile-footer>
                <h1 matLine>{{dish.name| uppercase}}</h1>
            </mat-grid-tile-footer>
        </mat-grid-tile>
    </mat-grid-list>
    <app-dishdetail [dish] = "selectedDish"></app-dishdetail>
</div>
```

### menu.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Dish } from '../shared/dish';
import {DISHES } from '../shared/dishes';
import { DishService } from '../services/dish.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu',
  templateUrl: './menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu.component.scss']
})

export class MenuComponent implements OnInit{

    dishes : Dish[];

    selectedDish : Dish;

  constructor(private dishService: DishService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dishes = this.dishService.getDishes();
  }

  onSelect(dish: Dish){
    this.selectedDish = dish;
  }

}
```

## Header component

### header.component.html

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <span><img src="/assets/images/logo.png" height=30 width=41></span>
  <a mat-button><span class="fa fa-home fa-lg"></span> Home</a>
  <a mat-button><span class="fa fa-info fa-lg"></span> About</a>
  <a mat-button><span class="fa fa-list fa-lg"></span> Menu</a>
  <a mat-button><span class="fa fa-address-card fa-lg"></span> Contact</a>
</mat-toolbar>

<div class="container jumbotron"
    fxLayout="row"
    fxLayout.sm="column" 
    fxLayout.xs="column" 
    fxLayoutAlign.xs="start center"
    fxLayoutAlign.sm="start center" 
    fxLayoutAlign.gt-sm="center center" 
    fxLayoutGap="10px">

  <div fxFlex fxFlex.gt-sm="50%">
    <h1>Ristorante Con Fusion</h1>
    <p>We take inspiration from the World's best cuisines, and create a unique fusion experience. Our lipsmacking creations
      will tickle your culinary senses!</p>
  </div>
  <div fxFlex fxFlex.gt-sm="20%">
    <img src="/assets/images/logo.png" alt="Logo">
  </div>
  <div fxFlex></div>
</div>
```

### header.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

    title = 'Header works!';

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

El menú funciona perfectamente. Puedo compartirlo contigo si lo necesitas. Mi repositorio es privado y puedo compartirlo contigo.

Aquí está [el enlace al stackblitz del repositorio](https://stackblitz.com/github/antoinecomp/conFusion). Devuelve este error.

```
Error in /turbo_modules/@angular/compiler@8.2.3/bundles/compiler.umd.js (2603:21)
Can't resolve all parameters for MenuComponent: (?).
```

## Versions

Es angular8.2.2

Comment: Has puesto todo el código menos donde aparentemente está el problema: la clase `MenuComponent`

Comment: @PabloLozano Lo estoy poniendo ahora, gracias. ¡Era el único que trabajaba bien! Pero es verdad

Comment: Por algún motivo que ahora mismo no alcanzo a ver, el compilador no es capaz de saber qué parámetro recibe el constructor de la clase MenuComponent. Pero por lo que veo en tu enlace (a Github, no a Stackblitz), el servicio DishService parece declarado correctamente...

Comment: @PabloLozano Diablos! ¿Qué me aconsejas que haga en este caso?

Comment: Hay veces que configurar algo dos veces lo desconfigura: prueba a quitar de la lista de providers del módulo (en app.module.ts) el servicio o a dejar la etiqueta `@Injectable()` del servicio vacía. En teoría al poner `@Injectable({providedIn:'root'})` no necesitas declararlo en el módulo